# Bookshelf resolves promise but does not save into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I want to know why using [Bookshelf.js](https://bookshelfjs.org/) leaves Promises resolved, but actually does not save anything on a PostgreSQL database

The code was successfully working, but suddenly It stopped working, I'm using an AWS server with a Windows instance, and one thing I tried is to restart the server.

The first thing noticed, is that after the reboot, some Windows environment variables dissapeared, I added the Node.js, NPM, and PostgreSQL commands, but the code keeps on resolving without inserting.

In the code example below I added functions with the same pattern... create an instance of a Bookshelf model and save it.

```
 new Invoice(Info).save().then(model => {
      console.log('Saved Invoice');
      SaveAddOn(model.id, AddOnData);
      console.log('Line 546', model.id)
      SaveReceiver(model.id, ReceiverData);
      console.log('Line 548', model.id)
      SaveIssuer(model.id, IssuerData);
      console.log('Line 550', model.id)
      SaveConcepts(model.id, ConceptsData);
      console.log('Line 552', model.id)
      if(TaxesData!=null) {
        SaveTaxes(model.id, TaxesData, true);
        console.log('Line 555', model.id)
      }
      SaveRelatedInvoices(model.id, RelatedInvoicesData);
      console.log('Line 558', model.id)
      CheckStatus(model.id,re, rr, tt, id);
      console.log('Line 560', model.id)
      resolve(model.id);
    })
```

One other thing is that the `console.log()` functions inside the `then()` method are not working, but every `console.log()` outside, they do...

I believe this is a common issue with Bookshelf, but I hope somebody can help me on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this happened because some dependencies inside **node_modules** were broken after installing another package.

After being overwhelmed and frustrated on how to resolve the problem I merged a local **node_modules** backup and the code started to work again.